# Flagging low quality answer

Tags: discussion, answers, flagging

I was reviewing the first post of Hop Hunter on this question : ["FV" abbreviation in BrewDog recipe](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/17330/fv-abbreviation-in-brewdog-recipe)

I find it doesn't answer the question, but I hesitate to flag it.

Answers that are not based on any facts, just on "I think it is this" usually don't bother me because an opinion can be welcome sometimes.  However, in this case, the answer has already been posted, so this one doesn't add anything more.

What do you think?

Comment: I find it hard to flag an answer that has been accepted by the OP. If the guy who asked is satisfied with the answer, I think the only thing we can do is improve the answer by commenting it. Of course, if the answer is totally incorrect, then flagging it is a must.

Comment: In my example, one answer was already accepted, but it was not that one I was flagging.  Some times, questions are protected to avoid this.

Comment: I see. Well, it doesn't happen very often to me, but if you're confident that it doesn't add anything at all, then I see no problem in flagging it.